# Xslt: How to split a string and add a class to two words

Tags: xml, function, xslt, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I need to highlight the two first words in a string (HTML header) with red by adding a CSS class, and `tokenize` is what I'm looking at right now. How exactly can this be done? If possible at all.

Some pseudo code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(title, '\s+')">
    // ......
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:text>className</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>

</xsl:for-each>
```

How do I pick out each word in the result?

Though, tokenize may not be the solution. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use **tokenize** here, especially if you wanted to cope with other word separators other than single spaces (the second argument of **tokenize** allows a regular expression to be specified.

Anyway, in your case, it might be worth assigning the results of tokenize to a variable, and then taking different action for the first two words. Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <h1>
         <xsl:variable name="words" select="tokenize(title, ' ')"/>
         <span class="className">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($words[1], ' ', $words[2])"/>
         </span>
         <xsl:for-each select="$words[position() &gt; 2]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </h1>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML as an example

```
<data>
   <title>This is a test</title>
</data>
```

The following is output

```
<h1>
   <span class="className">This is</span> a test
</h1>
```

Comment: Great! But I got a case where one word repeated itself twice at the end of a sentence; in the for-each loop. Can  concat(' ', .)  be modified to prevent that?

Comment: Can a give an example of that in your question, please? Thanks!

Comment: The last word in the line 'To do to' I get 'To do to to'. The last word repeats its self. On another sentence it works fine. Do you know what can cause this? The same happens when I do  <xsl:value-of select="$words[position gt 2]" separator=" " />

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried my XSLT on `<data><title>To do to</title></data>` and I get `<h1><span class="className">To do</span> to</h1>`. It may help if you edit your question to show the XML you are using, as well as more full XSLT sample. Thanks!

Comment: May be some oddity in my CMS, I'll look into it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**You are close. Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <h1>
    <xsl:variable name="vWords" select="tokenize(., '\s+')"/>
    <span class="className">
      <xsl:value-of select="$vWords[not(position() gt 2)]" separator=" "/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </span>
      <xsl:value-of select="$vWords[position() gt 2]" separator=" "/>
  </h1>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>Red cat and a mouse</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<h1><span class="className">Red cat </span>and a mouse</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage of using tokenize() is that you lose the delimiters between tokens. A better solution here is xsl:analyze-string:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="title" regex="\s+ (or whatever)">
  <xsl:matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() le 4">
         <span class="xxxx"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

If you use a regex that allows for punctuation between words, this ensures that the punctuation will not be lost. You could also reverse the test and have a regex that matches words rather than interword delimiters.

The position() le 4 test allows for the fact that the sequence might start with either a word or an inter-word delimiter.